# Undefined split method while using request.url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, url, parameters

I am trying to get the current url of my page and the parameters that go with it. When I manually put the url in, the undefined split method error does not occur. I have tried the following:

request.url

request.original_url

request.fullpath

adding in

```
id = request.original_url
```

and adding this function

```
def original_url
  base_url + original_fullpath
end
```

What does currently work for me is below, but I cannot have the same url and parameters every time so this method won't work later on.

```
   #parse current url
    #what I would like below in comment
    #id = request.original_url
    url =   "http://127.0.0.1:3000/reviews/new?id=2"
    uri    = URI.parse(url)
    params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
    id     = params['id'].first
```

Any help or tips on if I'm missing something would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The absence of query parameters in url was causing it.

```
url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/reviews/new" # no query params
uri = URI.parse(url)
query = uri.query # nil
params = CGI.parse(query) # Undefined split Exception
```

This solves it:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
if uri.query
  params = CGI.parse(uri.query)
  id = params['id'].first
end
```